# Ice Cream comes or come?

Tags: grammar

Which of the two is correct?

1. Ice cream comes in many flavors.
2. Ice cream come in many flavors.

I am in doubt because we say *Police have arrested the thieves*.

Thank you.

Comment: *Ice cream* is normally uncountable, like milk or applesauce. When arrested by *the* police, I expect I'll be able to count the policemen/women/persons, but in general it's kind of irregular, do you shouldn't use it as a standard.

Comment: @medica persons??? O.o

Comment: Maybe that's why the countability of *ice cream* is confusing to you... *Police" is short for policemen/women/persons (gender unspecified). Not "O.o" at all to me (Ame). [Essentially, police is an irregular plural of policeman or policewoman, but it can also represent police as an institution or a single body – however it is quite a rare word because it is always treated as a plural.](http://www.englishlessonsbrighton.co.uk/police-uncountable-plural-noun/)

Comment: Ice cream is uncountable.  If you want to talk about several, use "kind" as a counter..."He likes several kinds of ice cream."  "We sell several kinds of ice creams."  "Ice cream comes in many favors."

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question,

> Ice cream comes in many flavors

This can work too :

> Ice creams come in many flavors